# ARM GCC: Conflicting CPU architectures

Tags: c++, c, gcc, arm

After upgarding to ubuntu 18.04 I can no longer compile my application. I'm using mbed-cli with an st nucleo board. This is the output from the command `mbed compile`

```
[Warning] test.c@1926,32: unknown option after '#pragma GCC diagnostic' kind [-Wpragmas]
Link: sensors
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o: Conflicting CPU architectures 13/1
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-setjmp.o): Conflicting CPU architectures 13/1
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-setjmp.o)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[ERROR] /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o: Conflicting CPU architectures 13/1
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-setjmp.o): Conflicting CPU architectures 13/1
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-setjmp.o)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[mbed] ERROR: "/usr/bin/python" returned error code 1.
[mbed] ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python -u /home/user/examples/mbed-os/tools/make.py -t GCC_ARM -m nucleo_f411re --source . --build ./BUILD/nucleo_f411re/GCC_ARM" in "/home/user/examples"
```

Comment: Might be same issue describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44153706/1207195

Comment: When compiling with mbed ensure you use a supported tool chain. You might be forced to use gcc 5

Comment: Not related to post that @AdrianoRepetti commented on.

Answer (score 5):

It is a Ubuntu 18.04 specific issue. It has already been raised [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1772332)

The workaround is to install `arm-none-eabi-gcc` from the PPA. Here are the instructions:

- Remove the installed one:

  ```
  sudo apt remove gcc-arm-none-eabi
  ```
- Install the one from the PPA:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-embedded
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I cannot comment OlivierM answer, but have important addition.

As stated before by OlivierM, you should delete installed software and install new from embedded repository, but if you installed gcc-arm-none-eabi from main rep, it will also install binutils-arm-none-eabi, which will conflict with gcc-arm-embedded.

- So you should remove gcc-arm-none-eabi and binutils-arm-none-eabi:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove binutils-arm-none-eabi
  sudo apt-get remove gcc-arm-none-eabi
  ```
- Now install from the PPA:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-embedded
  ```